# Tutorial implementation of analytic tableaux

Tags: implementation, tutorials, tableau

I am re-reading John Harrison's wonderful *Handbook of Practical Logic and Automated Reasoning*, and he has a rather idiosyncratic presentation of analytic tableaux.

What other tutorial implementations of analytic tableaux for first-order logic are there?

Comment: If anyone else is confounded with Harrison's transition in his book, it's because he appears to be implicitly relying on Prawitz's [An improved proof procedure](https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/abs/10.1111/j.1755-2567.1960.tb00558.x) (1960), which would have been really nice to have known.

Comment: (I mean, this is buried in the trail of citations; it's not really Harrison's fault. But it would have been nice to know to also look at that paper.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- As far as I'm aware, [leanTAP](https://formal.kastel.kit.edu/beckert/pub/LeanTAP.pdf) was written in just a few lines of Prolog, and it works with first-order formulas in Skolem normal forms. There's a [tutorial implementation in OCaml](https://moodle.risc.jku.at/pluginfile.php/10562/mod_resource/content/12/07-fol3.pdf) which looks similar to it.
- The [Tree Proof Generator](https://www.umsu.de/trees/) ([GitHub](https://github.com/wo/tpg)) written in JavaScript works with general first-order formulas (though it seems to pre-process formulas into negation normal forms and then translates the proof back in the end?). It also implements equational reasoning (as described [here](https://www.umsu.de/blog/2021/722)) and modal logic, along with some heuristic optimizations.
- [This paper](https://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/%7Elp15/papers/Isabelle/blast.pdf) discusses the implementation of a tableau prover (`blast` tactic) for Isabelle. I am not sure how it translates tableau proofs (which are essentially a space-efficient representation of sequent calculus) into Isabelle proofs (natural deduction), but I've also found [this](http://ceur-ws.org/Vol-2162/paper-03.pdf) discussion about such a translation in detail...

Comment: Note that tableau "sequents" are one-sided, so the inferences performed in a tableau proof will map quite cleanly to natural deduction.  (To show validity of an input formula, negate it and derive consequences using tableau rules until all branches are closed.)

Comment: @MichaelNorrish Ah yes, I was probably thinking about "signed tableau" and reducing the number of DNE/RAA rules...